# What are the packages naming conventions between mirrors and local cache?

Tags: package-management

I am wondering a lot why some packages naming doesn't seems to correspond between mirrors and local cache.

For example, using `apt-get --print-uri`, I got :

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends --print-uris vim
'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vim/vim_8.2.3995-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb' vim_2%3a8.2.3995-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb 1723566 MD5Sum:3b0145d5f4ab60dde45b0b02259c6d5d
```

And doing the `apt-get install` I got this file then available in the cache :

```
ls /var/cache/apt/archives/backup/vim_2%3a8.2.3995-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb 
/var/cache/apt/archives/backup/vim_2%3a8.2.3995-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

Removing it and manually downloading it and putting it in the cache with this link is not working as apt-get is redownloading it at `--reinstall` :

```
wet http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vim/vim_8.2.3995-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install --reinstall vim
ls /var/cache/apt/archives/vim*
/var/cache/apt/archives/vim_2%3a8.2.3995-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb  /var/cache/apt/archives/vim_8.2.3995-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

Could someone provide a rationale of the naming of packages between mirrors and local cache?

Comment: I wonder what your point is - that there is difference between the package and file names? - because there is.

Comment: This is a question and answer site manned by volunteers. No one here has anything to do with naming conventions.